# OpenGL ES3 android: built in variable gl_InstanceID

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, opengl-3

I am trying to implement instancing in my android-game - that is to draw 64 sprites in one draw-call.

I am following a tutorial based on the c-language

https://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-OpenGL/Instancing

the program crashes when I use the following syntax in the vertex-shader-code

```
vec2 offset = offsets[gl_InstanceID];
```

exception

```
09-19 17:28:18.315 3635-3674/? E/ShaderHelper: Error compiling shader: 0:47: L0002: Undeclared variable 'gl_InstanceID'
```

So why can I not access the instanceID variable? I've already set the GLcontextClientVersion to 3 in the customized GLSurfaceview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gl_InstanceID is a ES 3.0 feature. From the GLSL ES 3.00 spec chapter 3.4 we read:

> The directive “#version 300 es” is required in any shader that uses
>   version 3.00 of the language.  Any number representing a version of
>   the language a compiler does not support will cause an error to be
>   generated.  **Version 1.00 of the language does not require shaders to
>   include this directive, and shaders that do not include a #version
>   directive will be treated as targeting version 1.00.**

My humble guess is you missed typing "#version 300 es" as first line in the shader so the compiler assumes version 1.00.

Comment: Thanks I thought this should solve my problem since I missed typing it in the shader but I get the following error: **Error compiling shader: 0:7: L0003: Keyword 'attribute' is reserved**

Comment: @java http://www.shaderific.com/blog/2014/3/13/tutorial-how-to-update-a-shader-for-opengl-es-30 Keyword 'attribute' is exchanged with keyword 'in'. Some other keywords are changed too.